# How do I add color to detection curve graphs?

Tags: r, graph, colors

I have several detection curves that I've created using the ds function within the "Distance" package. An example of these detection graphs should be shown in the link below.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFHXZ.png)

An example of the code used to create these graphs...

```
Rap150.uni<-ds(data = Rap150, key = c("unif"), truncation = 150, 
    adjustment = NULL, transect = "point", convert_units = units)
plot((Rap150.uni), main = "150m - uniform AIC=114.95")
```

I need to use these graphs in a presentation and am not sure how to make these more visually appealing. I would like to

1. increase the text size of the graph's title and
2. Add color to both the bars of the graph and to the detection curve.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.